# what does line containing 'index ...' mean when patch created using git

Tags: linux, git, github

I was in `branch1`. I committed a few files using git command:

`git add file1.c`

`git commit`

And then created patch using git format-patch:

`git format-patch master..branch1`

Now the patch created has these lines on the top:

```
diff --git a/include/abc.h b/include/abc.h
index 2f5f1f3..f4aa268 888111
--- a/include/abc.h
+++ b/include/abc.h
```

My questions are:

1. What does line `index 2f5f1f3..f4aa268 888111` mean?
2. I think it might be related to some git hash. How can I verify those numbers from the git log? Basically what those numbers mean in `index 2f5f1f3..f4aa268 888111`?
3. `git log` shows very long numbers in the hash. How are they related, if at all?

Comment: Have you tried searching for index in the format-patch docs?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate though it's not precisely a duplicate because of your question #3. The thing to know about Git hash IDs is that you can *abbreviate* them, as long as the shortened one is unambiguous. Git sometimes shows you the full hash (which always works) and sometimes shortens them on its own. The blob hashes in the `index` line are shortened unless you use the `--full-index` option when making the diff.